# Notepad++ Regex help - Finding less than 6 chars in quotations

Tags: regex, notepad++

How would I go about creating a regex search to find numbers less than X characters long within quotes? Less than 6 chars in the following example:

```
"+3256974589654" <- Not this
"+5256974584654" <- Not this
"+6256974553654" <- Not this
"43567" <- This
"98765" <- This
```

**EDIT**
Just found this: [Unsupported operators in Notepad++/Scintilla regular expression syntax](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Unsupported_Regex_Operators)

Looks like something similar to `[0-9]{1,5}` will not work as `{m,n}` (where `m` and `n` are integers) are not supported.

**EDIT**
The regex I used was `"[0-9]{0,10}"`. Sadly Notepad++ does not support `{x,y}` therefore I ended up using a free editor called "Programmer's Notepad".

Comment: I got annoyed with these kind of issues in Notepad++ and switched to Programmer's Notepad too.  I wish more people would, and end ++'s dominance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Notepad++ (apparently) doesn't support `X{m,n}` syntax, you could work around it by `m` `X` followed by `n-m` `X?`. So for `[0-9]{1,5}` you could instead use:

```
[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?
```

Not the prettiest/fastest, but it should work. (Note that `[0-9]` can be replaced by `\d`)

(Make sure you are using the latest version of Notepad++, as `?` support was included in version 5.9)

Comment: @Dan Rasmussen I'm not quite sure how to go about using that but I tried using `"\d\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?"` however when I click search it shows every single number in quotation marks?

How would I use this and limit it to find results with only 5 numbers?

Please keep in mind I'm pretty new at writing regex.

Comment: @BPaner—The regex I gave is for `{1,6}`. For `{1,5}`, just remove the trailing `\d?`.

Comment: @DanRasmussen Do you mean like this: `"[0-9]\d\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?"` if so, that is not working. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @BPaner—`[0-9]` is equivalent to `\d`. You could do `"[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?"` to find a quoted number with between 1 and 5 digits.

Comment: @DanRasmussen Ah I see what you mean. I just tried `"\d\d\d\d\d"` and it is working perfectly! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of Notepad++ v6.0, PCRE syntax is available

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Unsupported_Regex_Operators

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
"[0-9]{1,5}"
```

And make sure the "Regular Expression" search mode radio box is selected:

[image]

Comment: Where would I find the Grep search checkbox?

Comment: Oops, not grep, "Regular Expression" under search mode.  (I was thinking "Text Wrangler").

Comment: I have tried using what you provided but it does not seem to be working? I keep getting "Can't find the text". Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @BPaner Its a pity, but Notepad++ does not support the quantifier `{1,5}`, nor does it support alternations, I see no possibility to achieve what you want with a single regex in Notepad++.

Comment: Yeah I think we both stumbled across that page at the same time haha. There must be a way around? Do you know of any other editors that support regex?

Comment: @BPaner vim supports extended/perl regex. Or you can download the [gnuwin utils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) and use grep. Note that you'll have some trouble, as windows does not support single quotes on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

From your given example, it seems that the longer digits has a plus (+) sign before digits itself, so you can capture those numbers less than 5 digit In length using double quotes as an indicater of search start.
Try to use the below regex
Find what: `"\d+`
Replace with:`your desired digits or numbers`